# Django (Accidental deletion of socket file, need to recreate)

Tags: python, django

Yesterday evening, I accidentally highlighted one too many files which I needed to delete from my Django environment and I accidentally caught the .sock file of my test production .sock file.

I have since tried everything I can think of to recreate the .sock file with no avail. Does anyone know of which method I should be following to recreate the sock file? As a last resort, I tried to manually create the .sock file and tried to run this command:

gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/testapp/test.sock test.wsgi:application

Although, I receive an error during the boot phase, ValueError("%r is not a socket" % addr)
which is understandable as I manually tried to recreate the file as a last resort option.

I have tried to rebooting nginx, reloaded the daemon, and tried to restart gunicorn, hoping that the .sock may be automatically recreated within my project folder, but I'm not having any luck.

Any tips would be most appreciated! Thank you :-)

Comment: dont manually create the file, leave that to the app which the socket file belongs to (whatever app that is). Restart it afterwards and it should get back on the track.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ahh, I feel so silly for trying to recreate the .sock file myself, I was just out of options at the time! I've followed your instructions, and I've noticed there's an error when I try to reboot the app (Which I know how to resolve) so I'm hoping after that error has been fixed and the service restarts, hopefully the sock file (As you say, is automatically recreated) :)